# como resolver error en laravel The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : \"\"mysqldump\"\" no se reconoce como un comando

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan, mysqldump

Estoy programando en mi proyecto de laravel un metodo para ejecutar un comando que permita realizar una salva de la base de datos. Esto es lo que he programado hasta el momento:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\ConfigGeneral;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql;


class BackupBaseDatosCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'backups:databasebd';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Salva de Base de Datos';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $config = ConfigGeneral::all()->first();

        $filename = '\backup_'.env('DB_DATABASE').'_'.date('Y').''.date('m').''.date('d').'_'.date('H').'_'.date('i').'_'.date('s').'.sql';

        //File::put($filename, '');

        MySql::create()
            ->setDbName(env('DB_DATABASE'))
            ->setUserName(env('DB_USERNAME'))
            ->setPassword(env('DB_PASSWORD'))
            ->setHost(env('DB_HOST'))
            ->setPort(env('DB_PORT'))
            ->dumpToFile($config->ruta_salva.''.$filename);
    }
}
```

Para ejecutar esto con `CMD` registre en mis variables de entorno lo siguiente `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` y funciona correctamente el comando cuando lo ejecuto usando `CMD`. Comprobado que funciona el `comando`, programe en mi controller un metodo para que cuando el usuario realice un llamado de la funcion `salvar_bd` realice la salva de la `Base de Datos`, el metodo programado en la controller es el siguiente:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

public function salvar_bd(Request $request)
{

    Artisan::call('backups:databasebd');

    $informacion = [

        'mensaje' => '<b style="color: black">Se ha guardado la configuraci&oacute;n del Servidor de Correo satisfactorimente </b>',
        'titulo' => '<b style="color: black">Operaci&oacute;n realizada</b>',
        'tipo_mensaje' => 'success'
    ];

    return response()->json(['informacion' => $informacion]);

}
```

Uso `Artisan` para hacer un llamado al comando para ejecutarlo. Pero el problema surge cuando ejecuto la funcion `salvar_bd` que lanza el siguiente error:

```
"message": "The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : \"\"mysqldump\"\" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n",
"exception": "Spatie\\DbDumper\\Exceptions\\DumpFailed",
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sis_control\\vendor\\spatie\\db-dumper\\src\\Exceptions\\DumpFailed.php",
"line": 17,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sis_control\\vendor\\spatie\\db-dumper\\src\\DbDumper.php",
        "line": 246,
        "function": "processDidNotEndSuccessfully",
        "class": "Spatie\\DbDumper\\Exceptions\\DumpFailed",
        "type": "::"
    },
```

Para poder ejecutarlo por consola `CMD` tuve que agregar esto `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` en la variable de entorno para que funcionara sin problemas; pero para que funcione la solicitud desde la ejecución del usuario donde debo agregarlo o que debo hacer para que este error no se salga. Existen otros metodos para programar que el usuario pueda realizar la salva de la base de datos?

Comment: Seguramente te falta configurar `dump_binary_path` con `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`.

Comment: revisando mi codigo me percate que en la class BackupBaseDatosCommand me falto indicar dump_binary_path. Ya elabore una respuesta dandole solucion al problema

Comment: y que colocaste en el archivo env setDumpBinaryPath(env('DUMP_BINARY_PATH'))
por ej: de manera local me pide C:/xampp/mysql/bin pero cuando lo subo aun servidor ejecuta pero no hace el backup escomo si no consiguiera esa ruta manejo cpanel si me pueden ayudar con eso le agradesco

Answer (score 1):

Revisando mi código me di cuenta que me faltaba indicar cual era la ruta del `Dump`, por lo que agregue un `setDumpBinaryPath` en mi función `handle` de mi `class BackupBaseDatosCommand`, me quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
public function handle()
{

    $config = ConfigGeneral::all()->first();

    $filename = '\backup_'.env('DB_DATABASE').'_'.date('Y').''.date('m').''.date('d').'_'.date('H').'_'.date('i').'_'.date('s').'.sql';

    //File::put($filename, '');

    MySql::create()
        ->setDumpBinaryPath(env('DUMP_BINARY_PATH'))
        ->setDbName(env('DB_DATABASE'))
        ->setUserName(env('DB_USERNAME'))
        ->setPassword(env('DB_PASSWORD'))
        ->setHost(env('DB_HOST'))
        ->setPort(env('DB_PORT'))
        ->dumpToFile($config->ruta_salva.''.$filename);
}
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien si se le presenta este problema.